# Tableview Cell with transparent distance between

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift.
I want to have tableview with transparent space between cells.

Lets say cell with 85 height and 12 - space to the next cell.

Now i have tableview with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if (section != 0) {
        return 12
    } else {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
}
```

That function make margins between cells, but seems like i can't make it transparent.

Is there a way to achieve a goal?

Comment: Just add bottom constraint to your  *cell*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement viewForheader

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let view = UIView() 
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)      
    view.isOpaque = false
    return view 
}
```

OR

```
 ->Cell
   ->contentView
      ->topView --- height(85)
      ->transparentView ----height(12)
```

Comment: thanks, got it. Will post the code if someone will need it later